# How to get "Roo support" to show up in Spring menu in STS

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, roo

New STS user here...  I was told that I need to add roo support into my STS (Spring Tool Suite) ide.  I was told to do it under Window -> Preferences -> Spring -> roo support.  Problem is, I don't have a selection called "roo support".  My menu goes from "Global Preferences Curator" to "Spring Boot."  What do I need to do to get the "roo support" option?  I'm running: 
Spring Tool Suite

Version: 3.6.3.SR1
Build Id: 201501121239
Platform: Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.1)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I needed to enable STS's old dashboard and from the dashboard go to "Extensions"  On that tab I added "Spring Roo" and "Spring IDE - Roo Extension."  I now have the tab. Not sure if I needed to add both to get the tab to appear, but it didn't appear after just adding "Spring Roo", but did appear after adding the second.